# Extending abstract class gives strange error while accessing variables

Tags: class, php

So guys I have this basic structure :

```
interface IModule {
    public function _prepareActionObj ();
}

abstract class Module implements IModule {

    private $_action = null,

            $_actionObj = null,

            $_actionHandlers = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_action = GetParamDefault('action', '');
        $this->_prepareActionObj();
    }

    private function _prepareActionObj () {
        $this->_actionObj = new $this->_actionHandlers[$this->_action]();
    }

}
```

So far nothing strange. But when I do this :

```
 class AdminHomeModule extends Module {
     private
         $_actionHandlers = array(
             '' => 'AdminModuleHomeAction'
         );
 }
```

and create new instance of AdminHomeModule I get this error

```
Undefined index: on line 22 in ....\interfaces\IModule.php
```

wich is exacly

```
$this->_actionObj = new $this->_actionHandlers[$this->_action]();
```

When I dump $this in Module constructor I get this

```
AdminHomeModule Object
(
    [_actionHandlers:AdminHomeModule:private] => Array
        (
            [] => AdminModuleHomeAction
        )

    [_action:Module:private] => 
    [_actionObj:Module:private] => 
    [_actionHandlers:Module:private] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

where as you guys can see I get two instances of _actionHandlers one for parent class and one from the current class that extends Module. I don't get why I have two _actionHandlers? Shouldn't I overwrite it when declaring it in child class, because right now _prepareActionObject is looking in the wrong place and I get this nasty error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is intended behavior. A `private` class initializer means that only **that** class is allowed to access this property. This doesn't change if the class is `abstract`.

What you can do instead is declare the abstract class initializer and the inheriting classes as protected and that way all inheriting classes will be able to access the same property.

```
abstract class Module implements IModule {

    protected $_action = null,

            $_actionObj = null,

            $_actionHandlers = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_action = GetParamDefault('action', '');
        $this->_prepareActionObj();
    }

    private function _prepareActionObj () {
        $this->_actionObj = new $this->_actionHandlers[$this->_action]();
    }

}

class AdminHomeModule extends Module {
    proteced
        $_actionHandlers = array(
            '' => 'AdminModuleHomeAction'
        );
}
```

**EDIT**: My mistake, I was giving advice without properly reviewing the code ...

[*redacted what was here*]

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer! It worked. But you are mistaken about one thing you can't declare other than public methods in interfaces as it is written in php doc "All methods declared in an interface must be public, this is the nature of an interface." :)

Comment: @shaddy You are correct. What I meant to say had to do with a recent change in abstract class visibility (that does not apply to you if you're using PHP < 5.5.0) and I redacted this since it's highly unlikely to affect you.